# Calculate $ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-\cos(x)}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, beta-function

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{3-\cos(x)}} $$

I need to calculate this using Beta \ Gamma functions.
I have tried the substitution $2 +\cos(x) = t$

Comment: Substitute $x$ by $\frac{x}{2}$, and see this [Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x= 2t$ then we have that, 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2dt}{\sqrt{3-\cos(2t)}} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot dt}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}}.$$
Then let $\sin(t)=u$ which gives,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot dt}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}}= \int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt{2}(1-u^4)^{-1/2}} du.$$
Let $u^4 = x$ then 
$$\int_{0}^{1} {\sqrt{2}(1-u^4)^{-1/2}} du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1} x^{-3/4}(1-x)^{-1/2}dx.$$

Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Excellent! many thanks.